# How to get the "open as window" option in my own apps

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

When I click the "Details" link in `chrome://extensions` many apps (but not all) have the "Open as window" option available in a drop-down menu:

[image]

How do I enable this drop-down menu for my own apps?

Comment: It seems the bug between different OS and versions. See: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449491 and  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224903

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is only available on [legacy packaged apps](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps) and [hosted apps](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple) (proper documentation broken).

Current-generation [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) cannot be opened in a tab, only as a collection of windows controlled by its own code - therefore the option is not present.

Answer (score -2):

This is a wrong answer, I didn't notice the os different, to the question, it's actually can be achieved.

You could go see this [guide](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-make-a-chrome-app-shortcut-for-any-web-app--cms-21221) for some information.

> That’s about the limit of Chrome app shortcuts on the Mac, but you can take them one step further in Windows or Chrome OS.

So, you couldn't get the shortcut enabled. But you can use another app called [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) to create an `App`.